# Overflow-X in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have overflow-x:hidden placed on the body tag of my page so that any content extending beyond the window will not be visible. No scroll bars show up, however, I can still scroll to the left / right to see the content (kinda defeats the purpose of overflow-x).

-ms-overflow-x: doesn't fix the problem either.

There is a wrapper 900px;

Inside the wrapper, there is a div inside:

```
width:100%;
padding-right:300px;
position:absolute;
left:200px;
```

I would like the inner div to hang over the right side of the window without causing it to scroll (and leaving a 200px space the its left).

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the width of the div is 100%, there should never be an overflow, since the div will always fit 100% of the viewport (assuming you haven't changed the size of your body tag).

As for the padding, the padding is added on after the width, so you're saying the div is 100% of the width of it's container (the body tag), and the padding is an additional 300px to the right, which will be invisible as it's out of the viewport.

You might want to try giving the div an explicit size width and experiment that way.

It may help to see an example of your markup as well, to get an idea of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

More HTML/CSS would be useful, but given what you have right now, my first thought is that your wrapper is still set to `position: static` (the default for HTML elements).

If you add `position: relative` to your wrapper, it will contain the absolutely-positioned element within it, and should constrain it to the overflow restrictions.

Additionally, you may want to look into the `box-sizing` property and how the W3C box model works. In short, your padding is adding to the width of the element, so it's actually (100% + 300px), which results in a size that is larger than the container.

If you don't want to mess with `box-sizing`, you can also add `max-width: 100%` to your absolute div to force it to not grow out of its container.